# php framework with sqlite, orm, i18n, l10n search addon

Tags: php, sqlite, orm, internationalization

I'm trying to find a PHPframework to build small, multilingual sites.

Do you know a PHP framework with support for:

1. Sqlite (it will be little sites so no performance problem and good for copy-paste from development to production)
2. ORM
3. i18n & l10n
4. easy search add-on
5. ability to just copy-paste no need to change config for going from devel machine to production (staging)

and if you know cms with those features put it too.

Comment: There are plenty of frameworks out there, depends on your other requirements. Have you found your answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 1.4.x comes with all this built it, except for searching which can be implemented using Lucen.

It has great documentation that walks you through the entire process of making a real and useful website using all the features you've mentioned. [See it here](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/).

Answer (score 0):

I am also searching for such a Framework. I found one called YII. It makes use of SQLITE by default. Very easy to setup. But I am not sure if it has all the features that you are looking for.

Link to Site: http://www.yiiframework.com/download/
Detailed Documentation is also available fro reference.